# Lucene 6.5.1 TokenStream contract violation: reset()/close() call missing, reset() called multiple times, or subclass does not call super.reset()

Tags: solr, lucene

Hi I have written class to test lucene index creation getting below error.

Lucene version 6.5.1.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: TokenStream contract violation: reset()/close() call missing, reset() called multiple times, or subclass does not call super.reset(). Please see Javadocs of TokenStream class for more information about the correct consuming workflow.
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.Tokenizer$1.read(Tokenizer.java:109)
at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.pattern.PatternTokenizer.fillBuffer(PatternTokenizer.java:162)
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.pattern.PatternTokenizer.reset(PatternTokenizer.java:151)
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenFilter.reset(TokenFilter.java:70)
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenFilter.reset(TokenFilter.java:70)
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenFilter.reset(TokenFilter.java:70)
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.miscellaneous.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilter.reset(RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilter.java:79)
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenFilter.reset(TokenFilter.java:70)
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.ngram.EdgeNGramTokenFilter.reset(EdgeNGramTokenFilter.java:110)
at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain$PerField.invert(DefaultIndexingChain.java:742)
at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processField(DefaultIndexingChain.java:447)
at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processDocument(DefaultIndexingChain.java:403)
at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocuments(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:273)
at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocuments(DocumentsWriter.java:433)
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocuments(IndexWriter.java:1382)
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.addDocuments(IndexWriter.java:1358)
```

Please find below standalone program and please check Analyzer create component part i am not getting proper example for 6.5.1 version.

Below code is used to create index for Id and name using lucene 6.5.1

```
public class LuceneWriteIndexExample
{
private static final String INDEX_DIR = "c:/temp/lucene6index";
static private Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer() {
    @Override
    protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName) {
        PatternTokenizer tokenizer = new PatternTokenizer(Pattern.compile("[/\\-\\t ,;\\.]+"), -1);

        TokenStream filter = new LowerCaseFilter(tokenizer);
        filter = new TrimFilter(filter);
        //filter = new ICUFoldingFilter(filter);
        filter = new RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilter(filter);
        filter = new EdgeNGramTokenFilter(filter, 1, 25);

        return new TokenStreamComponents(tokenizer, filter);
    }
};



public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    IndexWriter writer = createWriter();
    List<Document> documents = new ArrayList();

    Document document1 = createDocument(1, "Test 1");
    documents.add(document1);

    Document document2 = createDocument(2, "Test 2");
    documents.add(document2);


    //Let's clean everything first
    writer.deleteAll();

    writer.addDocuments(documents);
   // writer.flush();
    writer.commit();
    writer.close();
}

private static Document createDocument(Integer id, String name) throws IOException {
    Document document = new Document();
    document.add(new StringField("id", id.toString() , Field.Store.YES));
    document.add(new TextField("name", name, Field.Store.YES));
    TokenStream tokenStream = analyzer.tokenStream("customeName", name);
    document.add(new TextField("customeName", tokenStream));

    return document;
}

private static IndexWriter createWriter() throws IOException
{
    FSDirectory dir = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(INDEX_DIR));
    IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(new StandardAnalyzer());
    IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, config);
    return writer;
}
```

}

Comment: you want to store TokenStream toString() value in the document?

Comment: Yes i want store tokestream value for indexing.

Comment: what do you mean by tokenstream value? TokenStream toString() will be just a class name and hash, not the exact values of tokens

Comment: Same piece of code is working in  lucene 4.6.0 i dont know why is giving error in 6.5.1 .Please could you help to resolve this issue,